# How to deploy ASP.NET Core projects to Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, web-deployment

I keep trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core web application to Azure. The solution contains an API project and a server project. The API project contains a database for data and the server project contains a database for logins.

[image]

[The project is very similar to this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qu581omBjw0&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVowClAs8-6nYnfsOTma14P&index=55&ab_channel=kudvenkat)

Can someone please guide me through the deployment process.

Comment: Plenty of articles on the web- [EXAMPLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: `The API project contains a database for data and the server project contains a database for logins` Would you like to move on-premises database to Azure, or access your on-premises database from a web app hosting on Azure App Service?

Comment: I figured out that the httpClient was not reaching the api project.

Comment: @FeiHan I'm not yet familiar enough to anwer your question. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not waiting for the database to be created. It takes about 30 minutes for azure to create te database. also you need to set the server firewall on azure.